# How to get confidence scores from Spark MLLib Logistic Regression in java

Tags: java, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

UPDATE: I tried using the following way to generate confidence scores but its giving me an exception. I use the below code snippet:

```
double point = BLAS.dot(logisticregressionmodel.weights(), datavector);
double confScore = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-point));
```

And the exception I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: BLAS.dot(x: Vector, y:Vector) was given Vectors with non-matching sizes: x.size = 198, y.size = 18
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS$.dot(BLAS.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS.dot(BLAS.scala)
```

Can you please help? It seems like the weights vector has more elements (198) than the data vector (I am generating 18 features). They have to be of same length in the `dot()` function.

I am trying to implement a program in **Java** to train from an existing dataset and predict on a new dataset using the logistic regression algorithm available in Spark MLLib (1.5.0). My train and predict programs are as below and I am using a multiclass implementation. The problem is when I do a `model.predict(vector)` (notice the lrmodel.predict() in the predict program), I get the predicted label. But what if I need a confidence score? How do I get that? I have gone through the API and was unable to locate any specific API giving the confidence score. Can anyone please help me out?

Train Program (generates a **.model** file)

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        JavaSparkContext jsc = null;
        int salesIndex = 1;

        try {
           ...
       SparkConf sparkConf =
                    new SparkConf().setAppName("Hackathon Train").setMaster(
                            sparkMaster);
            jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
            ...

            JavaRDD<String> trainRDD = jsc.textFile(basePath + "old-leads.csv").cache();

            final String firstRdd = trainRDD.first().trim();
            JavaRDD<String> tempRddFilter =
                    trainRDD.filter(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<String, Boolean>() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID =
                                11111111111111111L;

                        public Boolean call(final String arg0) {
                            return !arg0.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(firstRdd);
                        }
                    });

           ...
            JavaRDD<String> featureRDD =
                    tempRddFilter
                            .map(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function() {
                                private static final long serialVersionUID =
                                        6948900080648474074L;

                                public Object call(final Object arg0)
                                        throws Exception {
                                   ...
                                    StringBuilder featureSet =
                                            new StringBuilder();
                                   ...
                                        featureSet.append(i - 2);
                                        featureSet.append(COLON);
                                        featureSet.append(strVal);
                                        featureSet.append(SPACE);
                                    }

                                    return featureSet.toString().trim();
                                }
                            });

            List<String> featureList = featureRDD.collect();
            String featureOutput = StringUtils.join(featureList, NEW_LINE);
            String filePath = basePath + "lr.arff";
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(filePath), featureOutput,
                    "UTF-8");

            JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> trainingData =
                    MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(jsc.sc(), filePath).toJavaRDD().cache();

            final LogisticRegressionModel model =
                    new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().setNumClasses(18).run(
                            trainingData.rdd());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(model);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(basePath + "lr.model"),
                    baos.toByteArray());
            baos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (jsc != null) {
                jsc.close();
            }
        }
```

Predict program (using the **lr.model** generated from the train program)

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        JavaSparkContext jsc = null;
        int salesIndex = 1;
        try {
            ...
        SparkConf sparkConf =
                    new SparkConf().setAppName("Hackathon Predict").setMaster(sparkMaster);
            jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream =
                    new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(basePath
                            + "lr.model"));
            LogisticRegressionModel lrmodel =
                    (LogisticRegressionModel) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();

            ...

            JavaRDD<String> trainRDD = jsc.textFile(basePath + "new-leads.csv").cache();

            final String firstRdd = trainRDD.first().trim();
            JavaRDD<String> tempRddFilter =
                    trainRDD.filter(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<String, Boolean>() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID =
                                11111111111111111L;

                        public Boolean call(final String arg0) {
                            return !arg0.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(firstRdd);
                        }
                    });

            ...
            final Broadcast<LogisticRegressionModel> broadcastModel =
                    jsc.broadcast(lrmodel);

            JavaRDD<String> featureRDD =
                    tempRddFilter
                            .map(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function() {
                                private static final long serialVersionUID =
                                        6948900080648474074L;

                                public Object call(final Object arg0)
                                        throws Exception {
                                   ...
                                    LogisticRegressionModel lrModel =
                                            broadcastModel.value();
                                    String row = ((String) arg0);
                                    String[] featureSetArray =
                                            row.split(CSV_SPLITTER);
                                   ...
                                    final Vector vector =
                                            Vectors.dense(doubleArr);
                                    double score = lrModel.predict(vector);
                                   ...
                                    return csvString;
                                }
                            });

            String outputContent =
                    featureRDD
                            .reduce(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2() {

                                private static final long serialVersionUID =
                                        1212970144641935082L;

                                public Object call(Object arg0, Object arg1)
                                        throws Exception {
                                    ...
                                }

                            });
            ...
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(basePath
                    + "predicted-sales-data.csv"), sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (jsc != null) {
                jsc.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tries, I finally managed to write a custom function to generate confidence scores. Its not perfect at all, but works for me for now!

```
private static double getConfidenceScore(
            final LogisticRegressionModel lrModel, final Vector vector) {
        /* Approach to get confidence scores starts */
        Vector weights = lrModel.weights();
        int numClasses = lrModel.numClasses();
        int dataWithBiasSize = weights.size() / (numClasses - 1);
        boolean withBias = (vector.size() + 1) == dataWithBiasSize;
        double maxMargin = 0.0;
        double margin = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < (numClasses - 1); j++) {
            margin = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < vector.size(); k++) {
                double value = vector.toArray()[k];
                if (value != 0.0) {
                    margin += value
                            * weights.toArray()[(j * dataWithBiasSize) + k];
                }
            }
            if (withBias) {
                margin += weights.toArray()[(j * dataWithBiasSize)
                        + vector.size()];
            }
            if (margin > maxMargin) {
                maxMargin = margin;
            }
        }
        double conf = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-maxMargin));
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double confidenceScore = Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(conf * 100));
        /* Approach to get confidence scores ends */
        return confidenceScore;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it doesn't seem to be possible. Looking at the source code you probably can extend it to return these probabilities.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala

```
if (numClasses == 2) {
  val margin = dot(weightMatrix, dataMatrix) + intercept
  val score = 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-margin))
  threshold match {
    case Some(t) => if (score > t) 1.0 else 0.0
    case None => score
  }
```

I hope it can help to start find a workaround.

Comment: can you cite an example please? I went through the LogisticRegression.java from spark docs and was unable to find that method.

Comment: I am unable to find **raw2probabilityInPlace** and **raw2prediction** functions. Can you please help?

Comment: It is in the class org.apache.spark.ml.classificationLogisticRegressionModel. If it is simpler you can also do a copy of it with a different name and put these functions public.

Comment: Please note that I am using **org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegression** and not the one from **ml** package. There is a difference in both the cases. The former supports multiclass but the latter does not (I had already evaluated them earlier and the one from ml package supports only binary classification). Can you please help?

Comment: Updated the first comment. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks, can you please post the equivalent code in Java? I am using Java and not Scala (not aware of scala). It would help me immensely! Btw, I am using multiclass classification and not binary classification and my number of classes are around 12.

Comment: I updated my original post and provided the method in java as you have suggested in scala. But it seems there is an exception due to the mismatch of the length of weights and the data vector. Can you please help?